# Date Axis: Years label are truncated to the tens place

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

Using this sample: https://codepen.io/rapster/pen/MRxNrm?editors=1111

```
chart.data = [{"date":"2019-01-01","value":10},{"date":"2029-01-01","value":66},{"date":"2039-01-01","value":19},{"date":"2049-01-01","value":7},{"date":"2119-01-01","value":13},{"date":"2139-01-01","value":4}];
```

chart should start with 2019, but instead start at 2010... Is there a setting to configure amCharts so it starts at 2019?

Answer (score 3):

When date axis finds out that your data is each 10 years, it rounds the dates. To avoid this, you might want to set baseInterval of dateAxis to:

`dateAxis.baseInterval = {count:1, timeUnit:"year"};`

This will cause the columns to be narrow (each column will represent one year). To avoid this, you might set `series.dataFields.openDateX` and `series.dataFields.dateX` data fields and add additional data to your data set with dates when each column should end.

Alternatively you could just use CategoryAxis instead of Date axis here, might be the most simple solution.

Comment: Does CategoryAxis support dateformatter? From the docs, it sounds like it but ain't working with this sample https://codepen.io/rapster/pen/wbdKKO